# Is there a name for this 3D printing effect?

Tags: printing, 3d

I'm relatively new to 3D printing, but I've taken to it with much gusto. I wish I'd done this years ago.

Trying to solve a printing problem, and I've been stymied by not knowing the *name* for the effect I'm seeing - there is zero chance I'm the first one to discover this.

A minimum reproducible example is a triplet of vertical cylinders on a raft, it's clear that the tool path starts at one spot, runs a full circle around to end in that same spot, and it lingers long enough to extrude just a tiny bit more material that builds up in a vertical line.

[image: What's that vertical line called?]

This matches exactly the tool path shown in the slicer and this effect is repeatable no matter how many parameters I changed. I've done many dozens of test prints and am not getting anywhere.

These are 16mm across and are used as inserts into a tray holding vials to shim a narrower diameter tube, and the bump is enough to matter.  I have to make *thousands* of these and am hoping not to have to file them all down by hand.

If it matters, I'm using a Sindoh 3DWOX 2D and a 3DWOX 1 with PLA filament.

1. Is there a name for this effect?
2. Are there mitigations?

I'm starting to rethink this whole approach...

Comment: Aha. I've learned elsewhere that this is a "seam" - which makes sense - and many slicers have ways to ameliorate its effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was happy to find my own answer elsewhere.

First, that effect is known as a "seam", and one mitigation is known as "vase mode" (known in some slicers as "Spiralise Outer Contour"), which builds the cylinder in a continuous spiral from the bottom up with *no* seam. It can create really nice aesthetically-pleasing prints.

However, vase mode only works *for a single model* because stopping (and possibly retracting) to print a second model breaks the whole continuous-spiral thing.

So, if I had only a few of these to print, I'd do them one at a time, but given that I need thousands of them, I've found other approaches to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you already identified it's the z-seam you're seeing, you can choose to align your seam into different locations but it looks to me that your seam is bulging more than what I'd consider normal.

You could try ensuring that retraction is turned on and pick up the speed a little to reduce the time spent in that area.